# FT of a tempered distribution is a function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a question. When is the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution a function? I guess if the FT is a function, itself must also be a function. But I don't know how to go further. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is incorrect. Dirac's $\delta$ is a tempered distribution, and its Fourier transform is the function $\hat\delta(\xi)=1$. More generally, the Fourier transform of any bounded measure is a bounded function. Then it is easy to see that the same is true of its derivatives. For instance $\widehat{\delta'}(\xi)=i\,\xi$.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for correcting me. Is there any if and only if condition?

Comment: No, as far as I know.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! What if the tempered distribution is  a weak solution of heat equation with Lu=f, L is the heat operator and f is in some sobolev space and the initial value of u is also in some sobolev space? Can we get the conclusion that the FT of that tempered distribution is a function? I know it is beyond my original question but thanks for reading it.